# Laravel 5.3: get globally stored array records in view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I am have created one table with name `languages` and in this table, I stored all phrase and labels for each language:

[image]

Now I just want to access that all phrases in my each view. I have only one option for doing this:

```
class Language extends Model
{
   private static $_language;
   protected $fillable = ['phrase','english','french'];

   function __construct(){
      $this->_language = self::get()->toArray();
   }

   public static function phrase($key){
     return self::where(['phrase'=>$key])->get()->toArray();
   }
}
```

I just created a static function in my model and called it again and again whenever I have to draw label. But I think that's not a good approach, means if I have ten labels query will call ten times, and it will make my app slow. I just want to know is there any another way to do this with single time query execution?

Comment: You could just store all of the once at the start of the program into a global array.

Comment: can you please explain me how?

Comment: Without knowing your file structure (do you have an index.php that performs routing, are you using MVC, etc.) that would be difficult. But basically, as early as possible in page generation, call the phrase() method and get the array of language phrases. Set a variable in the global scope to that array.

Comment: using laravel 5.3

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Laravel, but I'm sure someone here does.

Comment: you can use [view composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#view-composers) although it seems kinda odd to re-implement the language translation as laravel already has one.also doing it this way might consume too much memory,you should think of implement this over redis/memcache.

Comment: i want access like this `trans('add_new_user')` in view, then how this is possible with `view composers` ?

Comment: @RahulSharma To do so you will need override the language translation package.you have an example here - https://github.com/Waavi/translation#load-translations-from-the-database